# Phaser multitouch (on laptop trackpad)

Tags: multi-touch, phaser-framework

I'm confused by how to skip the following condition when 1) holding down, and then 2) another tap on the screen to release the aim.  I think the secondary tap becomes the `activePointer` so I'm quite puzzled.

```
var holding_down = game.input.activePointer.isDown;

if (holding_down && game.input.pointer2.isUp) { cue.aiming = true; }
```

UPDATE: Please note that for the solution accepted, I had to differentiate between desktop and mobile usage. pointer1 & pointer2 work fine on mobile, but on desktop I had to do the following.

```
  if (desktop) {
    var holding_down = game.input.activePointer.leftButton.isDown;
    var second_tap = spacebar.isDown;
  } else {
    var holding_down = game.input.pointer1.isDown;
    var second_tap   = game.input.pointer2.isDown;
  }
```

Also note you need to declare the `desktop` var after intantating the `game` object. I then set the var in the `preload()` function: `desktop = game.device.desktop;`, otherwise it was giving the wrong value.  Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to figure out your question yesterday and today, but I remain confused. Could you restate your question or say what behavior you would like?

Comment: Thank you so much for looking. I'm build a game for mobile, but I'm using a mac trackpad to develop, which doesn't seem to register second taps when holding down (click down).  Is that clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that the secondary tap becomes the `activePointer`. Per the documentation, [`activePointer`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Input.html#activePointer) is "[t]he most recently active Pointer object."

Therefore, you'll want to make your checks against `game.input.pointer1` and `game.input.pointer2` instead.

So replace `activePointer` in your code with `pointer1` and that might get you closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the update and info! Glad you got it working.